# text box value whilst sitting inside an array - PHP

Tags: php

I know for a fact option 1 is right as it works for me.

**OPTION 1**

```
echo "<input type='text' name='text1' id='text1' value='".$_SESSION['txt']."'>";
```

But in a situation where text boxes are a result of an array, if I change the above to the following is it correct? I know the `name='text1[]'` bit is right however can some one tell me how do I change the `value` attribute in the option 2?

**OPTION 2**

```
echo "<input type='text' name='text1[]' id='text1' value='".$_SESSION['txt[]']."'>";
```

Comment: i don't get it why `$_SESSION['txt[]']` ? please explain what are you trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can put the array in to session :-

```
$my_array=array('ct', 'dg', 'se', 'ir');
 // put the array in a session variable
$_SESSION['code']=$my_array;

foreach($_SESSION['code'] as $key=>$value)
{
// and print out the values
 echo "<input type='text' name='text1[]' id='text1' value='".$_SESSION[$key]."'>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I get the idea